# What scripting language do I use for HTML5 Canvas in Animate CC?

Tags: jquery-animate, adobe

In Animate CC, in Create New, I selected HTML 5 Canvas. However, when I need to put some scripts to the project I don't know which language to use. I tried both ActionScript and Javascript but neither of them worked for me and since the software is new, I couldn't find a lot of online help.

For example, using JavaScript (I put all the scripts on one layer):

Frame 1, I put: 
var count = 0;
alert(count);

Frame 2, I put: 
count = count + 1;
alert(count);

Frame 20, I put: 
this.gotoAndPlay(1); // go to frame 2 and play again

The first "alert (count)" on frame 1 worked, but "alert(count)" on frame 2 didn't kick in.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am a bit puzzled that "this.gotoAndPlay()" works - this is an ActionScript function, after all. It would work if defined in some library JS that gets included - is that the case? If so, maybe this library function contains all the AS functions and I can actually use both JS and AS functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Both JavaScript and ActionScript are supported in Animate CC. However, ActionScript is supported in ActionScript-based projects and JavaScript is supported in HTML5-based projects.

This missing part in my script is "this". I need to use "this.count" instead just "count". By default variable scope is valid only in their frame code so in order to make the variable accessible from other frames I need to use "this.variableName".

Frame 1:    this.count = 0;

Frame 2:    this.count++;
            alert(this.count);

Frame 20: this.gotoAndPlay(1);